# How to Represent Composite keys in Hibernate using Annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

So I reverse engineered some tables from my db and when I try to save my object to the db I get the following  error:

Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.mycode.Block from com.mycode.Account has the wrong number of column. should be 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

The Domain objects Are Block which contains a number of Account Objects:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "Block")
public Set<EAccount> getAccounts() {
    return this.Accounts;
}
```

Account has a Composite key of Id and Role. This has been setup in a seperate Class:

```
@Embeddable
public class BlockAccountId implements java.io.Serializable {

private long blockOid;
private String accountRole;

public BlockAccountId() {
}

public BlockAccountId(long blockOid, String accountRole) {
    this.blockOid = blockOid;
    this.accountRole = accountRole;
}

@Column(name = "BLOCK_OID", nullable = false)
public long getBlockOid() {
    return this.blockOid;
}

public void setBlockOid(long blockOid) {
    this.blockOid = blockOid;
}

@Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ROLE", nullable = false, length = 10)
public String getAccountRole() {
    return this.accountRole;
}

public void setAccountRole(String accountRole) {
    this.accountRole = accountRole;
}
```

So I want to know. How can I Link the tables Block and account on blockOid but still ensure the account table has both blockOid and accountRole as a composite key.

Any examples would be greatly appreciated!

N.B this is a Block (One) to Account (Many) relationship.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is to place your association directly in the embedded id component.

> **Hibernate reference documentation**
>
> - [Section 5.1.2.1.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id). id as a property using a component type ()

Example (Only write the important getter() and setter())

```
@Entity
public class Block {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="BLOCK_OID")
    long blockOid;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.block", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<Account>();
}

@Entity
public class Account {

    @EmbeddedId BlockAccountId id;

    public Account()
    {
        this.id = new BlockAccountId();
    }

    public void setBlock(Block pBlock) {        
        this.id.setBlock(pBlock);
    }

    public Block getBlock() {
        return this.id.getBlock();
    }

    public String getAccountRole() {    
        return this.id.getAccountRole();
    }

    public void setAccountRole(String accountRole) { 
        this.id.setAccountRole(accountRole);
    }
}


@Embeddable
public class BlockAccountId implements java.io.Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)    
    private Block block;

    @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ROLE", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String accountRole;

    public BlockAccountId() {

    }

    //Implement equals and hashcode
}
```

The corresponding database table are :

```
CREATE TABLE  block (
  BLOCK_OID bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`BLOCK_OID`)
) 


CREATE TABLE  account (
  ACCOUNT_ROLE varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  block_BLOCK_OID bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ACCOUNT_ROLE`,`block_BLOCK_OID`),
  KEY `FK_block_OID` (`block_BLOCK_OID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_block_OID` FOREIGN KEY (`block_BLOCK_OID`) REFERENCES `block` (`BLOCK_OID`)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually had this originally but had an extra @id in the Block object. Then the error message threw me off and made me think it was the AccountId class(the embedded composite id). Looks like you have to watch how hibernate reverse engineers things. Thanks for a consise answer

Comment: Great answer.  Just want to mention that for ordinary composite keys without any constraints, adding the @Id annotation to each getter method for a field that is part of the composite key is sufficient to satisfy Hibernate so it doesn't complain about how the class file doesn't reflect the database meta-data after it actually queries the database.  Of course you can and ought to specify the other relationships if there are any [eg: ManyToOne(...), etc.], but if all you have is a composite key and want to get Hibernate to leave you alone about it, that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

based on hibernate documentation  here's the [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id)

based on it you can do the following :

@Entity
public class Account {

```
@EmbeddedId BlockAccountId id;

@MapsId(value = "blockOid")
@ManyToOne
private Block block;

public Account()
{
    this.id = new BlockAccountId();
}

public void setBlock(Block pBlock) {        
    this.block = pBlock;
}

public Block getBlock() {
    return this.block;
}

public String getAccountRole() {    
    return this.id.getAccountRole();
}

public void setAccountRole(String accountRole) { 
    this.id.setAccountRole(accountRole);
}
```

}