# Composite Primary Key leads to org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to use a composite primary key for a table `City` that is not supposed to exist if it does not get assigned to a `Country` (it is supposed to be a many-to-one *identifying relationship*).

My problem is first of all that `ChildId` (see nested class) has a `@GeneratedValue` that is `null` after I initialize `Child` like here:

```
List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<>();    
City graz = new City(austria, "Graz");
// Runs without exceptions but graz.getCityId().getId() will be 'null'
cityList.add(graz);
cityList.add(new City(austria, "Wien"));
```

Any it seem that because of it I am getting an `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException` exception:

Full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.mahlzeit.datamodel.address.City#com.mahlzeit.datamodel.address.City$CityId@8a62f66]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:635)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:631)
    at com.mahlzeit.datamodel.HibernateTest.addAddressData(HibernateTest.java:63)
    at com.mahlzeit.datamodel.HibernateTest.populateDatabase(HibernateTest.java:35)
    at com.mahlzeit.datamodel.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:31)
```

I don't know if I can do this that way. If yes, how can I make this  work?

**City.java**

```
@Entity
public class City implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4374113410767348574L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private CityId cityId;

    private String cityName;

    public City(Country country, String cityName) {
        setCityId(new CityId(country));
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String countryName) {
        this.cityName = countryName;
    }

    public CityId getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }

    public void setCityId(CityId cityId) {
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class CityId implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8561021314776406519L;

        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        private Country country;

        public CityId(Country country) {
            this.setCountry(country);
        }

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Country getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(Country country) {
            this.country = country;
        }       
    }
}
```

**Country.java**

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2060021861139912774L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String countryCode;

    public Country(String country_code) {
        this.countryCode = country_code;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public void setCountryCode(String countryCode) { 
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `City` class the primary key is `CityId` and this class has 2 properties - `id` & `country`.

Please note that [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) is useful only when the property is also annotated with `@Id`, so there is no use of adding `GeneratedValue` for `id` property in `CityId` class, hibernate will just ignore that. Also you cannot add `@Id` for this property because this class represents `@Embeddable`

Now in your program you are setting the `CityId` like this:

```
public City(Country country, String cityName) {
    setCityId(new CityId(country));
    this.cityName = cityName;
}
```

The constructor of `CityId` is :

```
    public CityId(Country country) {
        this.setCountry(country);
    }
```

So finally you are creating 2 cities with same country:

```
City graz = new City(austria, "Graz");
new City(austria, "Wien");
```

Also as you are not setting value for the `id` of `CityId` class it will always be `null`. So both the `city` objects `graz` & `wien` have same primary key because of the combination of `country` reference & `id` (which is null in this case).

---

Also you need to have proper mapping between your entities, refer to this SO post for similar example:

[How to Represent Composite keys in Hibernate using Annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080611/how-to-represent-composite-keys-in-hibernate-using-annotations)

Coming to the `id` property of `CityId`, you have to set that explicitly or else it will always be `null`.

Comment: Well yes but how would I generate `CityId.id`? This just *has* to be somehow autogenerate like an `@Id`. How would I do that? I don't want to have to set it explicitly because I would have to look up myself if that value is still available or not. There must be a way to use an auto generated (or auto increment) value..

Comment: @StefanFalk, my answer is on why you are getting the issue and to fix it you have to set that id explicitly, auto-generation will not work. But I see you already have a separate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976363/hibernate-generatedvalue-in-embedded-always-null , and steve and given answer, have you tried that option.

Comment: No I wasn't on the machine but I will try it in a few hours when I got there. I will accept your answer here. If you want I can let you know if I could solve the id-problem and how. :)